# Creating DLL with SWIG from VS2010  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl axtoi

Tags: visual-studio-2010, swig, program-entry-point, php-extension

I'm trying to generate a dll file with swig from Visual Studio 2010, I created and compiled my wrapper.cpp code successfully and add every library dependencies to my project. Now when I try to build release version of my project with .dll target extension, I've got the following error:

```
  Generating non-SAFESEH image.
1>Ccrypto_wrap.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl axtoi(char const *)" (?axtoi@@YAHPBD@Z) referenced in function __wrap_axtoi
```

That's wired, cause every other external symbols in wrapper.cpp have been resolved except

`axtoi`! I mean for example in my wrapper.cpp I have 2 references of `axtoi`:

(1)

```
ZEND_NAMED_FUNCTION(_wrap_axtoi) {   char *arg1 = (char *) 0 ;   zval
**args[1];   int result;
     SWIG_ResetError();   if(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() != 1 || zend_get_parameters_array_ex(1, args) != SUCCESS) {
    WRONG_PARAM_COUNT;   }

      /*@SWIG:C:\Users\user\Desktop\Ccrypto\Lib\php\utils.i,62,CONVERT_STRING_IN@*/
      if ((*args[0])->type==IS_NULL) {
        arg1 = (char *) 0;
      } else {
        convert_to_string_ex(args[0]);
        arg1 = (char *) Z_STRVAL_PP(args[0]);
      }
      /*@SWIG@*/;

      result = (int)axtoi((char const *)arg1);
      {
        ZVAL_LONG(return_value,result);
      }
      return;
    fail:
      SWIG_FAIL();
    }
```

(2)

> SWIG_ZEND_NAMED_FE(axtoi,_wrap_axtoi,NULL)

I created the shared object of my class successfully in Linux and I included it in my php codes and it works fine, so I tried to check `axtoi` in my shared object in Linux and I figured out an strange thing! when I grep `axtoi` inside my shared object I got:

```
         U _Z5axtoiPKc
0006ccf1 T _wrap_axtoi
```

but for every other symbols for example `itoax` which its usage is the same as `axtoi` in the wrapper code I have:

```
00093660 T _Z5itoaxi
0006e19f T _wrap_itoax
```

I have several similar symbols which are used exactly the same as `axtoi` in my wrapper.cpp code as mentioned above, but I didn't get any unresolved external symbol errors. Any ideas?

Comment: `axtoi` sounds like a typo - are you sure you didn't type it instead of `atoi` somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I didn't type anything, this function is one of the swig generated wrapper code functions, I mean xxx_wrap.cpp. when I try to build dll from this file and my class I get this error.

Comment: Posting an error message without any of the source or steps leading up to it isn't very useful.

Comment: I edited my question with some more details, hope someone can help me this time

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:
It seems that swig wrapper code generator in c++ option call `axtoi()` function instead of `atoi()` function. It needs to be edited in wrapper.cpp generated with SWIG and then the error is solved.